# How can I easily get the manufacturer and model of my monitor?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, display, cmd.exe

How can I get the manufacturer and model of my monitor from within Windows, without having to disconnect and manhandle a 27" inch monitor looking for a label that may not exist, **or download any third-party software?** It seems odd that there's no **native, software-only** solution to do this on Windows 7.

---

**UPDATE #1:**

This question was initially claimed to be a duplicate of another question. **It isn't a duplicate of the proposed question** because:

1. *The proposed question is specific to laptops.*
2. *The proposed question is incredibly broad, seeking to cover all (laptop) hardware with a single solution. My question, by contrast, is asking about a piece of hardware specific to desktop computers. I did so knowing that it is notoriously hard for Windows 7 users to obtain specifics for said piece of hardware with a native software solution. This is evidenced by the fact that none of the answers to the supposed original question correctly answer mine, despite said question having existed since 2009, and by the fact that the only correct answer to my question is an obscure command-line one.*
3. *The proposed question doesn't specify native-only solutions, which is an important requirement for me and many other users who want to be able to accomplish such a relatively simple task without downloading or installing additional software.*

---

**UPDATE #2:**

I accepted the current answer because it is the right solution to the question I asked, even though **it doesn't work in my specific instance** due to bad EDID values. For that specific issue, I created a [follow-up question here](https://superuser.com/questions/1245250/why-is-my-monitor-showing-up-as-generic-non-pnp-monitor).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Get Manufacturer and Model of Monitor(s) via Command Line

You can use [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) for the task of getting the monitor make and model information from a **Windows** system. I tested and confirmed this works with both **Windows 7** and **Windows 10**.

**Bonus**

Furthermore, if you need to get the serial number, I've included a resource below that has some PowerShell script examples that I also confirmed works with both **Windows 7** and **Windows 10**.

**It's important** to run the command prompt (and PowerShell) elevated as administrator to ensure this works properly.

---

### Command Example

```
wmic desktopmonitor get Caption, MonitorType, MonitorManufacturer, Name
```

### Example Results

[image]

[image]

---

### Further Resources

- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)
- [SpiceWorks - PowerShell Get Monitor Serial Number, etc](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/658220-get-monitor-manufacturer-model-and-serial-number)

  > ```
  > $LogFile = "C:\test\monitors.txt"
  >
  > function Decode {
  >     If ($args[0] -is [System.Array]) {
  >         [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($args[0])
  >     }
  >     Else {
  >         "Not Found"
  >     }
  > }
  >
  > echo "Name, Serial"
  >
  > ForEach ($Monitor in Get-WmiObject WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi) {  
  >     $Name = Decode $Monitor.UserFriendlyName -notmatch 0
  >     $Serial = Decode $Monitor.SerialNumberID -notmatch 0
  >
  >     echo "$Name, $Serial" >> $LogFile
  > }
  > ```

  [image]

Answer (score 6):

Try the free [DumpEDID](http://nirsoft.net/utils/dump_edid.html) utility created by Nir Sofer of [NirSoft](http://nirsoft.net). It's a command line utility, so you will need to run it from a [command prompt](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/win8/cmd_prompt.php). There's no installation process needed; you can run the program after extracting it from the downloaded zip file. I've included output from the program below as an example of the information it provides.

```
C:\Program Files\NirSoft\dumpedid>dumpEDID
DumpEDID v1.06
Copyright (c) 2006 - 2017 Nir Sofer
Web site: http://www.nirsoft.net

*****************************************************************
Active                   : No
Registry Key             : DISPLAY\HWP2904\1&8713bca&0&UID0
Monitor Name             : HP S2031
Serial Number            : 3CQ0311PV2
Manufacture Week         : 31 / 2010
ManufacturerID           : 61474 (0xF022)
ProductID                : 10500 (0x2904)
Serial Number (Numeric)  : 16843009 (0x01010101)
EDID Version             : 1.3
Display Gamma            : 2.20
Vertical Frequency       : 50 - 76 Hz
Horizontal Frequency     : 24 - 83 KHz
Maximum Image Size       : 44 X 25 cm (19.9 Inch)
Maximum Resolution       : 1600 X 900
Support Standby Mode     : No
Support Suspend Mode     : No
Support Low-Power Mode   : Yes
Support Default GTF      : No
Digital                  : No

Supported Display Modes  :
     720 X  400  70 Hz
     640 X  480  60 Hz
     800 X  600  60 Hz
    1024 X  768  60 Hz
    1280 X  720  60 Hz
    1440 X  900  60 Hz
    1280 X 1024  60 Hz
    1600 X  900  60 Hz

*****************************************************************

*****************************************************************
Active                   : No
Registry Key             : DISPLAY\HWP2904\4&2199b20&0&UID16843008
Monitor Name             : HP S2031
Serial Number            : 3CQ0311PV2
Manufacture Week         : 31 / 2010
ManufacturerID           : 61474 (0xF022)
ProductID                : 10500 (0x2904)
Serial Number (Numeric)  : 16843009 (0x01010101)
EDID Version             : 1.3
Display Gamma            : 2.20
Vertical Frequency       : 50 - 76 Hz
Horizontal Frequency     : 24 - 83 KHz
Maximum Image Size       : 44 X 25 cm (19.9 Inch)
Maximum Resolution       : 1600 X 900
Support Standby Mode     : No
Support Suspend Mode     : No
Support Low-Power Mode   : Yes
Support Default GTF      : No
Digital                  : No

Supported Display Modes  :
     720 X  400  70 Hz
     640 X  480  60 Hz
     800 X  600  60 Hz
    1024 X  768  60 Hz
    1280 X  720  60 Hz
    1440 X  900  60 Hz
    1280 X 1024  60 Hz
    1600 X  900  60 Hz

*****************************************************************

C:\Program Files\NirSoft\dumpedid>
```

In the above example, from the "Monitor Name" line I can determine the monitor was manufactured by HP with a model number of S2031.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my $1.02 solution designed mainly for enterprise sysadmins with hundreds of computers to manage; you can steal the core logic and tailor for non-domain windows systems.  Also pulls in the elusive Dell Monitor SN's and manufacture date for warranty purposes.

```
# Pulls the computer and monitor serial numbers from the local machine
$ComputerNames = $env:COMPUTERNAME  
# Alternately specify multiple computer names as follows
# $ComputerNames = "TargetComputer1", "TargetComputer2", "TargetComputer3"

Function Get-ModelSerialNFO { #version 1.04
 #Asseses Target computer or computers passed in as a parameter, collects information about Model and Serial Numbers, returns $ComputerMdlSerResults
[cmdletbinding()]   

Param (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [string[]]$ComputerNames = $env:COMPUTERNAME
      )

Begin
{
    ####### GET YOUR LOCAL DOMAIN NFO #########
    $DomainName = $env:USERDOMAIN
    $Root = [ADSI]"LDAP://RootDSE"
    Try { $DomainRoot = ($Root.Get("rootDomainNamingContext")).ToUpper() }
    Catch { Write-Warning "Unable to contact Active Directory because $($Error[0]); aborting script!"; Start-Sleep -Seconds 5; Exit }
    $DomainDN = "DC=$DomainName,$DomainRoot"
    ########## END: GET YOUR LOCAL DOMAIN NFO #########

    ########### GET YOUR LOCAL DOMAIN CONTROLER THAT LOGGED YOU ON ###########
    #   $logonServer is used as -Server to the Get-ADComputer below, not sure that this is necessary(?)
    $logonServer = nltest /dsgetdc: /force
    $logonServer = $logonServer.item(0)
    $logonServer = $logonServer.TrimStart("DC: \\")
    ######### END: GET YOUR LOCAL DOMAIN CONTROLER THAT LOGGED YOU ON ###########


    ######### GET YOUR LOCAL SITE NAME ############
    $sAMAccountName = "$env:ComputerName`$"
    $searcher = [adsisearcher]"(&(objectClass=Computer)(sAMAccountName=$sAMAccountName))"
    $searcher.SearchRoot = "LDAP://$($DomainDN)"
    $searcher.SearchScope = 'Subtree'
    $searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add('CanonicalName') | Out-Null
    ########### END: GET YOUR LOCAL SITE NAME ############

    ########## SET YOUR LOCAL baseDN PATH ############
    $baseDN = "$DomainDN" #ALTERNATELY SPECIFY YOUR OWN baseDN path in AD
    ########### END: SET YOUR LOCAL baseDN PATH ###########

    FUNCTION Verify-ComputerName { #version 1.3
    #Verifies that you are connecting to the host you think you are; helps to identify DNS issues.
    [cmdletbinding()]

    Param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
            HelpMessage="Enter one or more computer names, separated by commas, or passed in through the pipeline.")]
            [array]$ComputerNames = $env:COMPUTERNAME,

            [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
            HelpMessage="Select this option to get verbose output, as the function runs.")]
            [switch]$INTERACTIVE
            )  

    BEGIN
    { 
        FUNCTION ConvertFrom-NSlookup {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        Param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory,Position=0)]
            [array]$NSlookupReply
            )
            $Hash = [ordered]@{}
            [int]$AddressCount = 0
            foreach($line in $NSlookupReply){
                if ($line -notmatch "======================================================================="){
                    switch -Regex ($line){
                        '\s*Server\s*:\s+(?<Server>.*$)'{$Hash.Server = $Matches.Server;Break}
                        '\s*Address\s*:\s+(?<Address>.*$)'{  
                                                            IF(($Hash.Server -ne $null) -and ($AddressCount -eq 0))
                                                            {
                                                                $Hash.SVR_Address = $Matches.Address; $AddressCount++; Break
                                                            }
                                                            ELSEIF(($Hash.Server -ne $null) -and ($AddressCount -eq 1))
                                                            {
                                                                $Hash.HOST_Address = $Matches.Address; Break
                                                            }
                                                            }
                        '\s*Name\s*:\s+(?<Name>.*$)' {$Hash.HostName = $Matches.Name;Break}
                        default {Break}
                    }
                }
            }
            RETURN $Hash; 
        } #END FUNCTION ConvertFrom-NSlookup

        FUNCTION CreatePSObjectForVerifyComputerName {
            $obj = New-Object PSObject
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ComputerName" -value $null
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "PINGTEST" -value $null
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "NSLOOKUP" -value $null
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "RemoteHostNameViaPSEXEC" -value $null
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "RemoteHostNameViaInvkCmd" -value $null
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ComputerNameVerified" -value $null
            return $obj
        }

    } #END BEGIN

    PROCESS
    {
        [ARRAY]$VeryifyComputerNameResults = $NULL
        FOREACH ($ComputerName in $ComputerNames)
        {        
            $ping = new-object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping

            $objVerifyComputerName = CreatePSObjectForVerifyComputerName
            $objVerifyComputerName.ComputerName = $ComputerName

            TRY {
                    $reply = $ping.send($ComputerName)
                    IF ($reply.status -eq "Success") 
                    {
                        $objVerifyComputerName.PINGTEST = "SUCCESS"         
                        IF ($INTERACTIVE) {
                                        Write-Host "SUCCESS: PINGTEST: Able to ping an IP that resolves to $ComputerName" -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Yellow
                                        } #Write-Log -Path $LogFile -Message "SUCCESS: PINGTEST: Able to ping $ComputerName" -Level Info

                        #RESET THE FOLLOWING VARIABLES FOR FOLLOWING IF-THEN LOGIC PROCESSES
                        $NSLookupRemoteHostAddress = $null
                        $RemoteHostName = $null

                        $NSLookupRemoteHostAddress = (ConvertFrom-NSlookup (nslookup $ComputerName)).HOST_Address
                        IF ($NSLookupRemoteHostAddress -ne $null) #If NSLookup returned an IP, execute the "hostname" command using psexec64.exe, against the IP that was resolved in DNS, in order to grab the RemoteHostName, as seen from the remote computer's perspective.
                        {   
                            IF ($INTERACTIVE) {
                                            $Message = "SUCCESS: NSLOOKUP: Resolved $ComputerName in DNS to: $NSLookupRemoteHostAddress"
                                            Write-Host $Message -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Yellow
                                            } #Write-Log -Path $LogFile -Message $Message -Level Info
                            $objVerifyComputerName.NSLOOKUP = $NSLookupRemoteHostAddress

                            $PSExecScriptBlock = {param ($NSLookupRemoteHostAddress)
                                                    $RemoteHostName = (& psexec64.exe \\$NSLookupRemoteHostAddress -s -nobanner -accepteula powershell -executionpolicy bypass -command "hostname" 2>$Junk)
                                                    return $RemoteHostName
                                                }
                            $PSExecJob = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $PSExecScriptBlock -ArgumentList $NSLookupRemoteHostAddress
                            $PSExecJob | Wait-Job -Timeout 30 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                            IF($PSExecJob.state -eq "Running")
                            {
                                WRITE-HOST "The job timer ran out for psexec64.exe, forcibly stopping and removing the job!" -ForegroundColor yellow -BackgroundColor Red
                                $PSExecJob | Stop-Job
                                $PSExecJob | Remove-Job
                            }
                            ELSE
                            {
                                $RemoteHostName = $PSExecJob | Receive-Job 
                                $PSExecJob | Remove-Job
                            }

                            IF ($RemoteHostName -ne $null) #Compare $ComputerHostName against $RemoteHostName
                            {

                                IF ($INTERACTIVE) {
                                                $Message = "SUCCESS: RemoteHostName: $RemoteHostName was obtainined on the remote IP $NSLookupRemoteHostAddress using PSEXEC64"
                                                Write-Host $Message -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Yellow
                                                } #Write-Log -Path $LogFile -Message $Message -Level Info
                                $objVerifyComputerName.RemoteHostNameViaPSEXEC = $RemoteHostName
                            }
                            ELSE
                            {
                                IF ($INTERACTIVE) {
                                                $Message = "FAILURE: RemoteHostName: Unable to obtain the hostname on the remote IP $NSLookupRemoteHostAddress using PSEXEC64, attempting Invoke-Command"
                                                Write-Host $Message -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor Yellow
                                                } #Write-Log -Path $LogFile -Message $Message -Level Warn
                                $objVerifyComputerName.RemoteHostNameViaPSEXEC = "FAILED"

                                #$Command = {hostname}
                                #$RemoteHostName = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock $Command
                                $JobScriptBlock = {param ($ComputerName)
                                                        $CommandScriptBlock = {$result = C:\Windows\System32\hostname.exe; return $result}
                                                        $RemoteHostName = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock $CommandScriptBlock
                                                        return $RemoteHostName
                                                    }
                                $Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $JobScriptBlock -ArgumentList $ComputerName
                                $Job | Wait-Job -Timeout 30 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                                IF($Job.state -eq "Running")
                                {
                                    WRITE-HOST "The job timer ran out for Invoke-Command, forcibly stopping and removing the job!" -ForegroundColor yellow -BackgroundColor Red
                                    $Job | Stop-Job
                                    $Job | Remove-Job
                                }
                                ELSE
                                {
                                    $RemoteHostName = $Job | Receive-Job 
                                    $Job | Remove-Job
                                }

                                IF ($RemoteHostName -ne $null) #Attempt to obtain RemoteHostName on NSLookupRemotehostAddress using Invoke-Command
                                {
                                    IF ($INTERACTIVE) {
                                                    $Message = "SUCCESS: RemoteHostName: $RemoteHostName was obtainined on the remote IP $NSLookupRemoteHostAddress using Invoke-Command"
                                                    Write-Host $Message -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Yellow
                                                    } #Write-Log -Path $LogFile -Message $Message -Level Info
                                    $objVerifyComputerName.RemoteHostNameViaInvkCmd = $RemoteHostName
                                }
                                ELSE
                                {
                                    IF ($INTERACTIVE) {
                                                    $Message = "FAILURE: RemoteHostName: Unable to obtain the hostname on the remote IP $NSLookupRemoteHostAddress using Invoke-Command"
                                                    Write-Host $Message -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor Yellow
                                                    } #Write-Log -Path $LogFile -Message $Message -Level Warn
                                    $objVerifyComputerName.RemoteHostNameViaInvkCmd = "FAILED"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        ELSE
                        {
                            IF ($INTERACTIVE) {
                                            $Message = "FAILURE: NSLOOKUP: Unable to resolve $ComputerName in DNS, SKIPPING: RemoteHostName Resolution"
                                            Write-Host $Message -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor Yellow
                                            } #Write-Log -Path $LogFile -Message $Message -Level Warn
                            $objVerifyComputerName.NSLOOKUP = "FAILED"
                        }

                        IF ($RemoteHostName -eq $ComputerName)
                        {
                            IF ($INTERACTIVE) { 
                                            $Message = "SUCCESS: MATCH: IP in DNS Remotely Resolves to: $RemoteHostName thereby matching: $ComputerName as expected!"
                                            Write-Host $Message -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor White
                                            } #Write-Log -Path $LogFile -Message $Message -Level Info
                            $objVerifyComputerName.ComputerNameVerified = $True
                        }
                        ELSE
                        {
                            IF ($INTERACTIVE) { 
                                            $Message = "FAILURE: MATCH: IP in DNS Remotely Resolves to: $RemoteHostName thereby NOT matching: $ComputerName as expected!"
                                            Write-Host $Message -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor Yellow
                                            } #Write-Log -Path $LogFile -Message $Message -Level Warn
                            $objVerifyComputerName.ComputerNameVerified = $False
                        }
                    }
                    elseif ($reply.status -eq "TimedOut")
                    {
                        IF ($INTERACTIVE) {
                                        Write-Host "FAILURE: PINGTEST: TimedOut: Unable to ping $ComputerName" -BackgroundColor Yellow -ForegroundColor Red
                                        $Message = "TROUBLESHOOTING: Ensure $ComputerName is online; check machine based firewalls (i.e. HBSS AV/HIPS) and/or LAN/CAN/WAN Firewalls"
                                        Write-Host $Message -BackgroundColor Yellow -ForegroundColor Red
                                        } #Write-Log -Path $LogFile -Message "FAILURE: PINGTEST: TimedOut: Unable to ping $ComputerName" -Level Warn
                                        #Write-Log -Path $LogFile -Message $Message -Level Warn
                        $objVerifyComputerName.PINGTEST = "TimedOut"
                    }
                    elseif ($reply.status -eq "DestinationHostUnreachable")
                    {
                        IF ($INTERACTIVE) {
                                        Write-Host "FAILURE: PINGTEST: DestinationHostUnreachable: Unable to ping $ComputerName" -BackgroundColor Yellow -ForegroundColor Red
                                        $Message = "TROUBLESHOOTING: Ensure $ComputerName is online; check machine based firewalls (i.e. HBSS AV/HIPS) and/or LAN/CAN/WAN Firewalls"
                                        Write-Host $Message -BackgroundColor Yellow -ForegroundColor Red
                                        } #Write-Log -Path $LogFile -Message "FAILURE: PINGTEST: DestinationHostUnreachable: Unable to ping $ComputerName" -Level Warn
                                        #Write-Log -Path $LogFile -Message $Message -Level Warn
                        $objVerifyComputerName.PINGTEST = "DestinationHostUnreachable"
                    }
                } #END TRY
                Catch { 
                        IF ($INTERACTIVE) {
                                        Write-Host "FAILURE: PINGTEST: Unable to ping $ComputerName" -BackgroundColor Yellow -ForegroundColor Red
                                        $Message = "TROUBLESHOOTING: Ensure $ComputerName is online; check machine based firewalls (i.e. HBSS AV/HIPS) and/or LAN/CAN/WAN Firewalls"
                                        Write-Host $Message -BackgroundColor Yellow -ForegroundColor Red
                                        } #Write-Log -Path $LogFile -Message "FAILURE: PINGTEST: Unable to ping $ComputerName" -Level Warn
                                        #Write-Log -Path $LogFile -Message $Message -Level Warn
                        $objVerifyComputerName.PINGTEST = "FAILURE"
                        $objVerifyComputerName.ComputerNameVerified = $False
                        #$reply = [ordered]@{}
                        #$reply.status = "Failure"
                        } #END CATCH
                $VeryifyComputerNameResults += $objVerifyComputerName
        } #END FOREACH ($ComputerName in $ComputerNames)
        RETURN $VeryifyComputerNameResults
    } #END PROCESS

    END
    {

    } #END END

    } #END FUNCTION Verify-ComputerName V1.3

    #Method in PS6 uses Get-ItemPropertyValue
    #i.e. $AGMRegValueValue = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $AGMRegKey -Name $AGMRegValue
    $GetRegValue_ScriptBlock = { param ($KeyPath, $ValueName)
        function Get-RegValue([String] $KeyPath, [String] $ValueName) 
        {
            (Get-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $KeyPath -Name $ValueName).$ValueName
        }
        Get-RegValue -KeyPath $KeyPath -ValueName $ValueName
    } #This function was written for PS4 to allow greater compatibility

    $LogonUIRegKey = "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\windows\currentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI"
    $LastLoggedOnDisplayName = "LastLoggedOnDisplayName"
    $LastLoggedOnUser = "LastLoggedOnUser"

} #end Begin

Process
{

    [ARRAY]$ComputerMdlSerResults = $NULL
    [ARRAY]$MonitorMdlSerResults = $NULL

    foreach($ComputerName in $ComputerNames)
    {
        $ManufacturerModel=$NULL; $SerialNumber=$NULL; $Monitors=$NULL

        IF((Verify-ComputerName -ComputerNames $ComputerName).ComputerNameVerified)
        {

            #get info about manufacturer and model
            $ManufacturerModel = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName | select name, manufacturer, model
            $SerialNumber = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BIOS -ComputerName $ComputerName | select SerialNumber
            $Monitors = gwmi -Namespace root\wmi -ComputerName $ComputerName -Query "SELECT * FROM WmiMonitorID WHERE Active='True'"

            $CurrentUser = $null; $Process=$null;$RemoteComputerLockedAndInUse=$null;$LogOffUser=$null;$UpdateLocalBIOS = $null;
            $CurrentUser = gwmi -Class win32_computersystem -ComputerName $ComputerName | select -ExpandProperty username
            IF($CurrentUser.Length -gt 1)
            {
                $SamAccountName = ($CurrentUser.Remove(0,5))
                $ADUserObj = Get-ADUser -Filter 'SamAccountName -like $SamAccountName' -Properties * -Server $logonServer -SearchBase $baseDN -SearchScope Subtree
                $LastUsedBy = $ADUserObj.DisplayName
            }
            ELSE
            {
                $LastUsedBy = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock $GetRegValue_ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $LogonUIRegKey, $LastLoggedOnDisplayName 2>$null
            }

            IF($Monitors.count -ge 1)
            {
                foreach ($Monitor in $Monitors)
                {
                    $obj = New-Object PSObject
                    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AttachedTo:" -Value $ComputerName
                    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Monitor_Manufacturer" -Value $(($Monitor.ManufacturerName | foreach {IF($_ -NE '00'){[char]$_}}) -join "")
                    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Monitor_Model" -Value $(($Monitor.UserFriendlyName | foreach {IF($_ -NE '00'){[char]$_}}) -join "") 
                    IF($(($Monitor.ManufacturerName | foreach {IF($_ -NE '00'){[char]$_}}) -join "") -eq "DEL")
                    {
                        $DellMonitorSN = $(($Monitor.SerialNumberID | foreach {IF($_ -NE '00'){[char]$_}}) -join "")
                        $DellMonitorSNMod = "xx-0"+ $DellMonitorSN.Substring(0,5) + "-xxxxx-" + $DellMonitorSN.Substring(5,3) + "-" + $DellMonitorSN.Substring(8,4)
                        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Monitor_SerialNumber" -Value $DellMonitorSNMod

                        $Day = $DellMonitorSN.Substring(7,1)
                        SWITCH ($Day){
                            {$Day -eq "A"}{$Day = "10"}
                            {$Day -eq "B"}{$Day = "11"}
                            {$Day -eq "C"}{$Day = "12"}
                            {$Day -eq "D"}{$Day = "13"}
                            {$Day -eq "E"}{$Day = "14"}
                            {$Day -eq "F"}{$Day = "15"}
                            {$Day -eq "G"}{$Day = "16"}
                            {$Day -eq "H"}{$Day = "17"}
                            {$Day -eq "I"}{$Day = "18"}
                            {$Day -eq "J"}{$Day = "19"}
                            {$Day -eq "K"}{$Day = "20"}
                            {$Day -eq "L"}{$Day = "21"}
                            {$Day -eq "M"}{$Day = "22"}
                            {$Day -eq "N"}{$Day = "23"}
                            {$Day -eq "O"}{$Day = "24"}
                            {$Day -eq "P"}{$Day = "25"}
                            {$Day -eq "Q"}{$Day = "26"}
                            {$Day -eq "R"}{$Day = "27"}
                            {$Day -eq "S"}{$Day = "28"}
                            {$Day -eq "T"}{$Day = "29"}
                            {$Day -eq "U"}{$Day = "30"}
                            {$Day -eq "V"}{$Day = "31"}
                        }

                        $Month = $DellMonitorSN.Substring(6,1)
                        SWITCH ($Month){
                            {$Month -eq 1}{$Month = "JAN"}
                            {$Month -eq 2}{$Month = "FEB"}
                            {$Month -eq 3}{$Month = "MAR"}
                            {$Month -eq 4}{$Month = "APR"}
                            {$Month -eq 5}{$Month = "MAY"}
                            {$Month -eq 6}{$Month = "JUN"}
                            {$Month -eq 7}{$Month = "JUL"}
                            {$Month -eq 8}{$Month = "AUG"}
                            {$Month -eq 9}{$Month = "SEP"}
                            {$Month -eq "A"}{$Month = "OCT"}
                            {$Month -eq "B"}{$Month = "NOV"}
                            {$Month -eq "C"}{$Month = "DEC"}
                        }

                        $DayOfManuf = "$($Day)-$($Month)-$($Monitor.YearOfManufacture)"

                    }
                    ELSE
                    {
                        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Monitor_SerialNumber" -Value $(($Monitor.SerialNumberID | foreach {IF($_ -NE '00'){[char]$_}}) -join "")
                        $DayOfManuf = "UNKNOWN"
                    }
                    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Monitor_ProductCodeID" -Value $(($Monitor.ProductCodeID | foreach {IF($_ -NE '00'){[char]$_}}) -join "")
                    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Monitor_WeekOfManuf" -Value $($Monitor.WeekOfManufacture)
                    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Monitor_YearOfManuf" -Value $($Monitor.YearOfManufacture)
                    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Monitor_DayOfManuf" -Value $DayOfManuf
                    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Monitor_LastUsedBy" -Value $LastUsedBy
                    $MonitorMdlSerResults += $obj
                }
            }

            IF($ManufacturerModel -ne $null -and $SerialNumber -ne $null)
            {
                $obj = New-Object PSObject
                $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ComputerName" -Value $ManufacturerModel.name
                $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Computer_Manufacturer" -Value $ManufacturerModel.manufacturer
                $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Computer_Model" -Value $ManufacturerModel.model
                $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "BIOS_SerialNumber" -Value $SerialNumber.SerialNumber
                $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Computer_LastUsedBy" -Value $LastUsedBy
                $ComputerMdlSerResults += $obj
            }
        }
    } #END foreach($ComputerName in $ComputerNames)

return $ComputerMdlSerResults, $MonitorMdlSerResults
} #End Process
End{} #End End
} #End FUNCTION #version 1.04
CLS
$RESULTS = Get-ModelSerialNFO $ComputerNames

#Sets a directory on your workstation to create the CSV log files
[string]$ResultsFilePath = "$env:SystemDrive\LOGS\ModelSerialNFO\" #Set Root Directory for the CSV Output File

########## CREATE USG LOG DIRECTORY, IF NEEDED ##########
IF(!(Test-Path $ResultsFilePath -PathType Container )){
Write-Host "WARNING: RESULTS CONTAINER `"$ResultsFilePath`" DOES NOT EXIST; 
ATTEMPTING TO CREATE..." -BackgroundColor Yellow -ForegroundColor Red
    TRY { 
        md $ResultsFilePath -Force -ErrorAction Stop
        $ResultsFolderExists = $true
        Write-Host "SUCCESS: RESULTS CONTAINER `"$ResultsFilePath`" WAS SUCCESSFULLY CREATED!" -BackgroundColor Blue -ForegroundColor White
    }
CATCH 
    {
            $ResultsFolderExists = $false
            Write-Host "FAILURE: UNABLE TO CREATE RESULTS CONTAINER, ABORTING ACTION(s)!" -BackgroundColor RED -ForegroundColor YELLOW
    }
}ELSEIF($RunningResults2csv){Write-Host "INFO: RESULTS CONTAINER `"$ResultsFilePath`" ALREADY EXISTS; CONTINUING SCRIPT..." -BackgroundColor Blue -ForegroundColor White; $ResultsFolderExists = $true}
######### END: CREATE USG LOG DIRECTORY, IF NEEDED ##########
$outFile = $ResultsFilePath + "$($OU)_COMPUTER_ModelSerialNFO_REPORT_" + (Get-date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy") + '.CSV' #Set the name of the CSV Output File
$outFile2 = $ResultsFilePath + "$($OU)_MONITOR_ModelSerialNFO_REPORT_" + (Get-date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy") + '.CSV' #Set the name of the CSV Output File

$RESULTS[0] | ft -AutoSize #This is your COMPUTER ModelSerial Info
$RESULTS[1] | ft -AutoSize #This is the attached MONITOR ModelSerial Info

$RESULTS[0] | Export-Csv -LiteralPath $outFile -NoTypeInformation #This is your COMPUTER ModelSerial Info - exported to a CSV file in your C:\Logs\ModelSerialNFO directory.
$RESULTS[1] | Export-Csv -LiteralPath $outFile2 -NoTypeInformation #This is the attached MONITOR ModelSerial Info - exported to a CSV file in your C:\Logs\ModelSerialNFO directory.
```